# Paypal Payment Data Transfer doesn't work with 'Click here' link

Tags: redirect, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a website uses Paypal to allow customers to purchase a service from our company. I am using Payment Data Transfer (PDT) to transfer the transaction ID back to our website (as a GET parameter) when the customer has completed the transaction on PayPal.

This works fine if the user waits 10 seconds as per the instructions on the final PayPal page. **However** if they click the link that says "Click here to return" then it redirects them to our website **but without the GET parameter containing the transaction ID!**

This is a problem for us, as we need the transaction ID in order to proceed with the purchase.
I have logged a fault with PayPal but they say they are working on it, and it doesn't look like they will fix it any time soon.

Is there any other way for me to obtain the transaction ID when a user is redirected to our site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a message from PayPal this morning saying

> We appreciate your patience. This message is to inform you that the issue was resolved through a recent live site update.

I have checked and can confirm that this does work correctly now.